# routing not working when trying with new component in tour of heroes

Tags: router

src/app/app-routing.module.ts:12:113 - error TS1005: ',' expected.
`{ path: 'newroutedisplay',component:NewRoutedisplayComponent}                                        },`
~
src/app/app-routing.module.ts:12:114 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

`{ path: 'newroutedisplay',component:NewRoutedisplayComponent}` this error is displayed

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes/heroes.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail/hero-detail.component';
import {NewRoutedisplayComponent} from './new-routedisplay/new-routedisplay.component';
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/heroes', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'detail/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent },
  { path: 'heroes', component: HeroesComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'newroutedisplay',component:NewRoutedisplayComponent}                                               },
  
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

this is my app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes/heroes.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail/hero-detail.component';
import { MessagesComponent } from './messages/messages.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import {CustomPipe} from './custom-pipe';
import { HeronewComponentComponent } from './heronew-component/heronew-component.component';
import {NewRoutedisplayComponent} from './new-routedisplay/new-routedisplay.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroesComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent,
    MessagesComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    CustomPipe,
    HeronewComponentComponent,
    NewRoutedisplayComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```